# Posted posts scheduling to unhide for new members

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, scheduled-posts

So I came up with this idea. It works like autoresponder, which send already prepared and scheduled content every 7(let's say) days to a all subscribers. And for a new subscriber it starts from the content 1, then later, sends content 2, etc.

I need this on wordpress, except there would be registrations and after registration new member could see only 1st posts. After 7 days, there would be more posts unhidden for him and so on. Another new member couldn't see that new posts, till he would wait for a 7 days.

Do you get the idea? Maybe you can help me out to find a plugin for this if it exists. If it doesn't maybe there are volunteers to create plugin like that? 
Anyway, I would really appreciate any of your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can count how many posts user can see like that: `(int) ( ( time() - strtotime( get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered ) ) / ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) + 1;`

So you add filter for `pre_get_posts` to show user as many posts as compleate weeks he has spendt on your website.

And to prevent seeing content for custom entered links you add filter to content, where you chack if current post is in avalable posts for current user.

And of course you show all for admins

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'prefix_pre_get_posts' );

function prefix_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    if( ! is_admin() && 'post' == $query->post_type ) { // is_main_query() ?
        $post_pre_page = null;
        if( is_user_logged_in() && ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
            $post_pre_page = (int) ( ( time() - strtotime( get_userdata(get_current_user_id( ))->user_registered ) ) / ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) + 1;
        } elseif( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            $post_pre_page = 0;
        }
        if( ! is_null( $post_pre_page ) ) {
            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $post_pre_page );
            // Show pastest posts first
            $query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );
            $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_filter_the_content' );

function prefix_filter_the_content( $content ) {

    if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
        return $content;
    $current_id = get_the_id();
    $allowed_posts = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    $flag = false;
    if( ! empty( $allowed_posts ) )
        foreach( $allowed_posts as $p )
            if( $current_id == $p->ID ){
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
    if( ! $flag ) {
        return __( 'Your are not able to see these post', 'your-textdomain' );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Simply add these code to your `functions.php`.

PS: to change 7 days to 3 ( for ex ) change it here '( **7** * 24 * 60 * 60 )' to '( **3** * 24 * 60 * 60 )'

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. This almost could do it, but it just adds random posts. I am looking for specific posts scheduling. Every post should be customized when it shows up for a new member.

Comment: Not shore i understend what u mean by "Every post should be customized when it shows up for a new member.", could u explane it ?
"but it just adds random posts" - thats strange.. it should show the pastest posts first ( may be there should be ASC not DESC in my example, but i think i wrote it fine ). Also if you have some extra `WP_Query's` or `get_posts` with custom parametrs such as `meta_key` then it might ruin our logic and we need to reset thows statements in our filter..

Answer (score 0):

Use a post meta field to store a numeric value representing the number of days someone has to have been a member before they can see this specific post.

Use `pre_get_posts` to check the age of the member and adjust the `$query` accordingly to include a `meta_query` that only shows posts with a value less than or equal to the member's age.

I can whip up some pseudo code if needed.